# What to do with children who don’t fit into their roles?

Tags: space-colonization

On a spaceship heading to a far off star system, there exist a community of children who have never seen earth, and where all gestated by artificial wombs and raised by surrogate robots.

There are three caste of children, all of which serve a distinct purpose. There are the “Big Kids” who are a laborer caste, and do jobs like building the colony, and act as a military force to defend the colony. They are stronger and bigger than the other caste, but not very intelligent. Then there are the “Smart Kids” who are intellectuals gifted with high IQs and serve as doctors and scientists to the colony. Finally, there are the “Love birds” who are a breeding caste. They are all designed to be extremely attractive and hormonal, and are the general population of the colony, who don’t do much work or any of that stuff, except for growing food. The robots are still there, helping with most of the work.

Then there are the “Duds” who were born into one caste but had genetic deformities. They can’t be killed, as the robots are specifically designed not to kill any of the children, so, what could they do with these children?

Comment: Hello Talos5, and welcome to Worldbuilding SE!  This question seems very opinion based to me.  Perhaps you could include some objective criteria for ranking answers?  Additionally, please take the [tour] and visit our [help] for more information about how the site works.

Comment: Talos, is this really the fifth account you've created on SE?  By now you know that questions need to be specific.  This is far too broad to answer well (and, from my point of view, so unrealistic that it's hard to fit an answer into the "children as adults" psycology you seem to be implying).  You'll probably get more by reading *Lord of the Flies* and *Children of the Corn* than by asking this here.

Comment: @JBH: I don’t know what’s happening. Every time I leave for an extended amount of time, my phone logs me out. I even registered but it still did nothing. I was originally Bryan, the guy who wrote “How would 17th century Salem react to modern clothing” but I was logged out. It’s really frustrating, and I’m starting to think about using other websites if the problem continues

Comment: @Talos5 You should be able to avoid the problem by [making a single registered account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/274942). You're currently using unregistered ones, and if cookies are cleared or other settings are changed, you'll lose access. Registering avoids that problem.

Comment: When I visit the [SE Users Page and search for Bryan](https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=5&tab=reputation&filter=week&search=bryan) a bazillion accounts pop up.  I can imagine the phone logging the account out - but not deleting it.  On the other hand, if it logs you out *before* you register, there's nothing to delete and nothing to go back to.  You have not yet registered this account.  Let's start there.  Register now, before the account logs out on your phone.

Comment: So, why not simply use the robots to do most of the work?

Comment: @JBH: How do you register wait never mind I see it

Comment: @JBH: it’s not working. Every time I press enter it just takes me back to the sign up page.

Comment: Long-distance diagnostics are very difficult and I don't use the phone app.  [Start here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/creating-accounts).  If you followed those instructions, then click the "meta-discussion site" link and post a question there.  That's the site that governs all the rest.  Once you have an account, you can use SO's contact form and tell them your email address and they'll merge everything they find with that address.

Comment: What does it says when you try to register?

Answer (score 3):

From an AI perspective, there's your group to pick from for dangerous jobs as well as to do simple menial work.

You also sterilize them as you wouldn't want them to breed.

An AI wouldn't waste them if they still has a use.

If you really wanted to be out there, there is your wetware to run your AI. The AI puts them in a suspended animation chamber and uses their brains for additional processing power.

Answer (score 1):

Same way societies on earth have dealt with the issue who reject but won't outright kill a deformed child, they expose them on a mountain or otherwise just don't feed them and they die naturally.

Alternatively they could be segregated and looked after either in some hidden place or in plain view of the rest much as western societies look after deformed or handicapped children.

Answer (score 0):

> On a spaceship heading to a far off star system, there exist a community of children who have never seen earth, and where all gestated by artificial wombs and raised by surrogate robots.

Keep this in mind.

> there are the “Duds” who were born into one caste but had genetic deformities

You don't have this problem, that's the simple way to deal with it. :-)

Civilizations that have reached the point where they can build robots capable of raising children and spaceships capable of interstellar travel will also have developed genetic engineering and control to the point where genetic abnormalities are eliminated.

As it sounds like conception and gestation are entirely artificial, probably outside a human body, the computers will simply test and repair any genetic issues before placing the embryo in the artificial womb.

As for being born to one caste or another, this would also seem unlikely.  An AI is going to genetically manipulate to ensure they're at least physically within the required parameters for their caste (as specified by whoever decided on this unstable caste system in the first place).

So it's a non problem - something than can't and won't happen in this scenario.

For exceptional circumstances (e.g. extremely rare failures of artificial wombs) the designers will have developed a protocol which, based on their principle of a caste system, would almost certainly be ruthless and direct destruction (and recycling) of the damaged embryos.  But this would be a very rare occurrence - not normally expected to happen at all.

Comment: Spolier Alert for my story. The people who sent the ship already knew the caste system would be unstable, and they knew that robots could take care of everything. But this ship wasn’t meant to actually colonize space, it was a social experiment, and the robots surrogates were just collecting data the whole time

Comment: Not exactly the same story but I seem to recall ["The Gold At Starbows End"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gold_at_the_Starbow's_End) had a related plot device.

Comment: @StehphenG: Just another thing. The duds aren’t real duds, they were created to be that way no accidents

Comment: You need to edit all these points into your question.  They are very important in order to try and make an answer.